# Cloudflare Workers main URL Redirect not working, Params as well

Tags: javascript, redirect, service-worker, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

Alief here.
I’m trying to use Cloudflare Workers to redirect a subdomain to a different domain, **but it’s not working**:
wa.example.com to wa.me/60123456789

And its path, **which works well**:
wa.example.com/WantToBuy to wa.me/60123456789?text=Want%20To%20Buy

Also, I’m unable to **remove params (fbclid)** from the subdomain in the same script.

The route for this worker is wa.example.com/*

How do I make it work? Thank you in advance.

Here is my full script:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(fetchAndApply(event.request))
})

async function fetchAndApply(request) {

let url = new URL(request.url);
let path = url.pathname;

var yourNumber = "60123456789"
const yourMessage = "'"+path+"'"

  number = yourNumber
  message = yourMessage.match(/(\d+|[a-z]+|([A-Z]([A-Z]+|[a-z]*)))/g).join('%20')

let whatsapp = 'wa.me/' + number + '?text=' + message

return fetch(whatsapp,request);
}

addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  let url = new URL(event.request.url)

  if (url.searchParams.has('fbclid'))
   url.searchParams.delete('fbclid')

  event.respondWith(
    fetch(url, event.request)
  )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Several problems here...

```
number = yourNumber
message = yourMessage.match(/(\d+|[a-z]+|([A-Z]([A-Z]+|[a-z]*)))/g).join('%20')
```

You should put `var` or `let` before these declarations of `number` and `message`. Otherwise, you are storing these into global variables, which could affect other requests, which is almost certainly not what you want.

```
message = yourMessage.match(/(\d+|[a-z]+|([A-Z]([A-Z]+|[a-z]*)))/g).join('%20')
```

When `match()` doesn't find any matches, it returns `null`. When you then call `.join()` on it, this will throw an exception. Indeed, running your script in the preview generates this error message in the console: `Uncaught (in response) TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of null`

This is why your script isn't working when no path is sent -- in that case, there are no matches of the regex.

```
let whatsapp = 'wa.me/' + number + '?text=' + message
```

You probably want to add `https://` to the beginning of this URL, otherwise it's not valid.

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
```

Your script uses `addEventListener('fetch')` more than once, with both listeners producing a result. The first listener that calls `respondWith()` will "win", so the second listener is ignored, hence why you find it isn't working.